# Dynamically load component in div - Angular5

Tags: angular, view, components

I was able to successfully create a button that on click loads another instance of my component into the DOM, but it loads it outside the component I want it to be inside which results with the CSS being off. When I add "editorComponents" to my page it currently looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

You can see from the inspection that in the second example all of the  tags are manually moved to where I want them to be.

Right now my code is as follows:

**home.component.html**

```html
<div class="row backgroundContainer">

  <div class="col-md-7 componentContainer">
    <app-editor></app-editor>
    <button (click)="addEditor()" type="button">Add Editor</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5 componentContainer">
    <app-bible></app-bible>
  </div>

  <div id="footerBox">
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**home.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { EditorComponent } from '../editor/editor.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addEditor() {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(EditorComponent);
    const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

So how do I make it so when I dynamically add an EditorComponent to my page it is added directly below the current "app-editor" in my html?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use your own `ViewContainerRef`. Currently you injecting root one and as you can see all your components appended to `<app-root>`.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { EditorComponent } from '../editor/editor.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  // Setup custom viewChild here
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;    

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addEditor() {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(EditorComponent);
    const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

Now inside your `home.component.html` put this where you want your editors to be instantiated

```
<div #container></div>
```

You can use any html tag here.

Now all your editors will be inside this block.

Comment: If you don't want to introduce a *div*, use `<ng-template #container></ng-template>`.

Comment: Add ViewChild to import from angular/core

Comment: You don't need the detectChanges() call do you?

Comment: `createComponent` with `factory` input is marked as deprecated: "Angular no longer requires component factories to dynamically create components. Use different signature of the createComponent method, which allows passing Component class directly."