# How to handle the below block component dynamically

Tags: angular, angular7

How to make this block component dynamic. What I mean, each time I click on drop down, the below block should be rendered keeping in mind that the block count should not exceed 6. In case, count == 6, close any of the block component and then you may click on the drop down. Moreover, **chart** data is dynamic that comes from the server once you click on the drop down and this response has to be replaced in the form of chart.

```
      <div style="margin: 10px; border: 1px solid blue; width: 30%;" #closeable1>
        <input class="rd" type="radio" checked/><small>Low</small>
        <input class="rd" type="radio"/><small>Medium</small>
        <input class="rd" type="radio"/><small>High</small>
        <input class="rd" type="radio"/><small>NA</ small>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closing1(closeable1)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
        </button>
          <hr>
        <div style="width:98%;" [chart]="stock2"></div>
      </div>
```

How to make this happen dynamically keeping the constraint in mind? I am attaching the image for your reference. Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution :

A "parent" component that handle this constraints
this parent component provides method like : addBlock(...) that manages blocks

Another solution : 
A service that manages blocks data list (and any constraints) and a component that subscribe this service and displays blocks .

Comment: Well, how to render the component dynamically on the click of drop down. One thing we need to take care of the graph as well. How to take it into account as every time response will change and graph will alter. Any idea to manage the graph /+ rendering of component.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question the best way, i think you want to load a code snippet dynamically inside a componenent. If it's the case i suggest to create a componentfor this div and take a look at this SO question you'll find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725651/dynamically-load-component-in-div-angular5) what exactly you need;

Comment: The click on drop down should do 2 things - 1.) It has to fetch the data from server to plot chart ,2.) It has to add that block component with graph plotted out of the data fetched from server. So, how to render the component along with graph inside that component.  You look at the image which is attached.

Comment: How to take care of `[chart] = stock2`, which is bounded to chart property. `stock2` is a variable having reference to the chart/graph. How to manage those things in typescript file.